# Can you recover deleted files on Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: data-recovery, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Kali Linux installed on WSL. In its bash I have accidentally overwritten a file in its file system (i.e., *not* under `/mnt/`) by a `mv` command.

Is there any way to recover it?

I have tried to recover it from both the embedded Linux file system and from the Windows one. Neither one worked.

- `testdisk` just tells me "`No disk found.`"
- Sure enough, there is no `sd*` under `/dev/`.
- From Windows, the Kali file system is stored in `c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Packages\KaliLinux.<hashes>\LocalState\rootfs\`, but Windows does not list any "previous versions" for anything there.

**EDIT:**

- Just for completeness, another way to access the Kali file system is through `\\wsl$\kali-linux\`.

Comment: You would have to use file recovery software within Windows not WSL since the file system is only virtual within WSL.  However, I don't have high hopes for that, but what is actually possible entirely depends on Windows 10 version you are running.